# Test fails : Jest + Vue 3 + Vuex + Typescript : TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jestjs, vuex

I have a component that we will call Form.vue that has a button that triggers a method of this component in which I have a store action.

I want to chain a .then() function after the dispatch but when I rerun the test it is now failing with this message : Error: Uncaught [TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined]

If I simply comment the .then() block the test will pass :

**->** do you have any clue about what to do to fix this ?

[image]

Form.vue

```
<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent } from "vue";
import { AxiosResponse } from "axios";

export default defineComponent({
  name: "Form",
  props: ["FormAnswers"],
  data(): {
    localFormAnswers: FormAnswersType;
  } {
    return {
      localFormAnswers: { ...this.FormAnswers },
    };
  },
  methods: {
    saveFormAnswers() {
      this.$store
        .dispatch("addFormAnswers", this.localFormAnswers)
        .then((response: AxiosResponse) => {
          some function there
            }
          }
        });
    },
```

store.ts

```
addFormAnswers(
    context: Context,
    formAnswer: FormAnswersType
  ): Promise<void> {
    return HTTP.post("/form-answers/", formAnswer);
  }
```

Form.spec.ts

```
describe("Form Answers component", () => {
  it("triggers saveFormAnswers method, when button is clicked", async () => {
    const $store = {
      dispatch: jest.fn(),
    };
    const wrapper = shallowMount(FormAnswers, {
      global: {
        mocks: {
          $store,
        },
      },
    });

    const spy = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, "saveFormAnswers");
    await wrapper.find("button").trigger("click");
    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mocking the `$store` wrong . You are providing a function returning `void` and not a function that returns a `Promise`.

try this

```
const $store = {
  dispatch: () => new Promise((resolve) => resolve()),
};
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your quick answer, however it seems I can get your code snippets to make my test pass, I have now this error message :   

console.error
Error: Uncaught [TypeError: this.$store.dispatch is not a function]

Comment: whops. sorry see my updated answer. a simple missing `() =>`